# Мобильное приложение Яндекс.почта игнорирует стиль тега img

Tags: вёрстка, img, мобильные-приложения, яндекс-почта

Доброго времени суток!

Работая над верской письма почтовой рассылки, я столкнулся с такой проблемой:
На мобильных приложениях Яндекс.Почта (iOS, Android) каким-то волшебным образом вырезаются стили из тега

Указываю:

```
<img src="адрес_картинки_280x280" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
```

Вообще везде с этим нет никаких проблем. В веб версии Яндекса эти свойства тоже отлично работают. Картинка скукоживается прекрасно.

Но именно в мобильных приложениях, после загрузки картинки, style куда-то пропадает и картинка показывается в фактическом размере (280 вместо 140). Можно поиграться и с другими свойствами, такими как border. До загрузки картинки рамка есть, а после загрузки - ничего. 
Кстати, просто атрибуты  width и height тоже игнорируются. Будто яндекс скачивает картинку и вставляет вообще свой img.

Есть один выход - отправлять картинку нужного размера. Но в этом случае с ретиной все будет очень плохо...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-нибудь сталкивался и знает как с этим быть?

p.s. Коллеги уже и в яндекс писали - там похоже забили болт и уже неделю не отвечают.

Comment: Может попробовать явно задать размеры картинки `<img src=""  width="140" height="140" >`, а не через стили.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Спасибо за ответ! Но я про это написал выше 
_"Кстати, просто свойства width и height тоже игнорируются"_

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Извиняюсь за ошибку. Это атрибуты, а не 'свойства' ) Исправил, чтобы было понятней.

Comment: задайте изображению display:block;

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с background-image вместо img:

```css
.abc {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-j2EmjBj2vqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAWY/oH9G4MVShwc/photo.jpg?sz=328"); /* 328x328 */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc"></div>
```